# Python np.lognormal gives infinite results for big average and St Dev

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, mean, standard-deviation

I am trying to draw the lognormal distribution for my data. using the following code:

```
mu, sigma = 136519., 50405. # mean and standard deviation
hs = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000) #mean, s dev , Size
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(hs, 100, normed=True)     
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 10000)
pdf = (math.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)))
#plt.axis('tight')
plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
```

As you can see, my mean and sigma are big values, it creates the problem that hs goes to infinity that gives an error. While if I put something like mu =3 and sigma =1, it works, any suggestions for big numbers?

Update 1 :

I corrected my code with the first answer, but now I only get a straight line :

```
 mu, sigma = 136519 , 50405 # mean and standard deviation

    normal_std = np.sqrt(np.log(1 + (sigma/mu)**2))
    normal_mean = np.log(mu) - normal_std**2 / 2
    hs = np.random.lognormal(normal_mean, normal_std, 1000)
    print(hs.max())    # some finite number
    print(hs.mean())   # about 136519
    print(hs.std())    # about 50405

#    hs = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000) #mean, s dev , Size
#    
    count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(hs, 100, normed=True) 

    x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 10000)
    pdfT = [];
    for el in range (len(x)):
        pdfTmp = (math.exp(-(np.log(x[el]) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)))
        pdfT += [pdfTmp]


    #plt.axis('tight')
    pdf = np.asarray(pdfT)
    plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
```

[image: image pdf]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters mu and sigma in [np.random.lognormal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html) are **not** the mean and STD of the lognormal distribution. They are the mean and STD of the *underlying normal distribution*, that is of `log(X)`. This means that by passing  `136519` for the mean you ask NumPy to generate numbers of size `exp(136519)` which is about `10**60000`, far beyond the double precision limits.

With [a bit of algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016650) you can get the correct parameters for `np.random.lognormal` from the ones you have.

```
mu, sigma = 136519., 50405.
normal_std = np.sqrt(np.log(1 + (sigma/mu)**2))
normal_mean = np.log(mu) - normal_std**2 / 2
hs = np.random.lognormal(normal_mean, normal_std, 1000)
print(hs.max())    # some finite number
print(hs.mean())   # about 136519
print(hs.std())    # about 50405
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked ,but I corrected my code, still : I get a straight line , shall you take a look at the new one ?

Comment: Because you are again using wrong values of mu and sigma there. Just one line is needed to compute `pdf`: `pdf = np.exp(-(np.log(x) - normal_mean)**2 / (2 * normal_std**2))`

Comment: I thank you again, I tried the code on my numbers, yet I am getting results that do not convince me, since now the question is different, I asked it in another question, can I link it here ?

Comment: Just one thing came to my mind : the 136519 I gave you as the mean, is the actual number of my data, and it is not converted to lognormal. I guess something is not clear for me, since in my code, the lognormal curve did not perfectly fit the bins